# Android issue adding months to calendar

Tags: android, calendar

I am adding 3 months to a calendar instance to get all the dates of three months. It works fine when all the three months are in the same year. I changed the month of device to November the app hangs and crashes. Here is my code.

```
private void GenerateData() {
    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    today.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1);
    month = today.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    System.out.println("this month "+today.getTime());
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println("Before "+cal.getTime());  
    if(count<=(month-11))
        cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, count);
    else{
        cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
        cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    }
    System.out.println("After "+cal.getTime());

    while (today.getTime().before(cal.getTime()))
    {
        List<Date> date = new ArrayList<Date>();
        if(today.get(Calendar.MONTH)==month){
            System.out.println("Dates of month "+month);
        }else{
            month++;
            System.out.println("Dates of month "+month);
        }
        while(today.get(Calendar.MONTH)==month) {
            Date result = today.getTime();
            //System.out.println(result);
            date.add(result);
            today.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }

        list.add(date);
    }
}
```

Comment: please post the logcat

Comment: No logcat, I guess. Endless loop...

Comment: No error returned in logcat. Only the app freezes and shows a popup message "App isn't responds.".

Comment: Ya thats right @Hanno Binder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an endless loop:

```
while (today.getTime().before(cal.getTime()))
{
    // ...
        month++;

    while(today.get(Calendar.MONTH)==month) {
     // ...
        today.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }

}
```

If `month` is 11, `month++` is 12, the second `while` loop never executes (months are only 0...11), `today` is not incremented and the outer loop repeats forever (or until `month` overflows and reaches `today`'s month again...).

`month = (month+1) % 12` instead of `month++` should do the trick.

Another solution is to make sure that `today` is really incremented in *every* iteration, like:

```
while (today.getTime().before(cal.getTime()))
{

  month = today.get(Calendar.MONTH);

  do {
    today.add( Calendar.DATE, 1 );
    date.add(today.getTime());
  } while ( today.get(Calendar.MONTH) == month );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

set the calender as,

```
    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    today.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1 );
```

and the increment the month 1 by 1 as you required like,

```
 today.add(Calendar.MONTH, j);
```

calculate the max. dates in month like ,

```
int daysInMonth = today.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

then get the dates in month like ,

```
 for (int i = 0; i < daysInMonth; i++) 
 {
    Log.e("dateTag", today.getTime());

    today.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
 }
```

increment the loop j, you will get the next months.

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand about Calendar objects.
If you want to add three monthes to an object, just add three months to the object.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(2014, 10, 11); // This means 2014/Nov/11

Calendar future = (Calendar) calendar.clone();
future.add(Calendar.MONTH, 3); // This means 2015/Feb/10

while (calendar.before(future)) {
    System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "/" + (calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "/" + calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}
```

And note that Calendar objects' January (the very first month of year) is **0**.

Comment: The OP said "to get all the dates of three months". Won't work your way.

Comment: @Hanno Binder ok, I improved my code but my point is the same. Simply determine the date of 3 months later. Then use it.

Comment: That's just what the OP does. - But the problem only occurred when he attempted to group all resulting dates by their corresponding month, which you don't address.